# defining styles only for non IE browsers

Tags: css

I am facing some blur effects problem in IE and would like to remove these blur effect if the page is opened in IE

These styles are defined in a stylesheet at different locations

What will be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Even though Edge is, in a sense, a rebranding/continuation of IE to make it look new and flashy, it is still fundamentally different in that it is updated more  semi-automatically and seamlessly. So, with Edge you don't have to worry as much about someone using an older version of it, as opposed to IE where you do have to worry. So, assuming you want to target all non-IE browsers and Edge, then the following code will work fine.

```
@supports (top:0){
    /*CSS code put here will only run in non-IE*/
}
```

A working example:

```css
#mytext:before {
  content: 'You are using IE < 11, or a REALLY outdate version of another browser'
}
@supports (top:0){
  #mytext:after {
    content: 'Horay! You are using A non-IE browser or Edge.'
  }
  #mytext:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mytext"></div>
```

The way the above code works is by testing to see if the browser supports the `@supports`. I would assume that, in many cases, if you have CSS to be used on non-IE browsers, then the CSS will likely not work in browsers that don't even support the `@supports` at-rule. Thus, this method fulfills a dual role: browser vendor testing, and browser support testing. The reason for why I used `top:0` is because it is likely the shortest CSS tag that is universally supported, with the added benefit of practically every web-programmer knowing that its universally supported. Other than that, there is absolutely nothing special about `top:0`: you can put whatever tag you want to test for in there.

Answer (score 0):

Paul Irish has a good, comprehensive list of browser-specific CSS hacks here:
http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

Note his statement at the top of that page about using conditional comments, which I personally suggest if you can edit the markup and are not limited to the CSS.

Answer (score -1):

The not IE conditional comment is a bit of a hack, and is therefore written slightly differently from when you are targeting IE.

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="not_ie.css" type="text/css" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Non-IE browsers will read this as they ignore the conditional comments completely and the comment is considered closed with the added extras. IE will read this as a "not IE" conditional and avoid calling the stylesheet.

Comment: But I think this conditionals one can use till IE9

Comment: @Tobag I answered this at 2016 and IE11 was introduced at 2017. Thanks for the downvote without the reasoning though.

Comment: It is still Important to know that the answer wont work for IE11. For some reason I cannot take back the downvote though.